# JEST test a NestJS service Model and Mongoose

Tags: angular, mongoose, jestjs, nestjs

I use JEST to test a service that connect with a MongoDB schema, so my problem is how I refer my mongoose model into the test specs file.

This is the service that inject the schema model

```
import { HttpService, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Article } from './interfaces/article.interface';

@Injectable()
export class ArticleService {
  constructor(
    private readonly httpService: HttpService,
    @InjectModel('Article') private readonly articleModel: Model<Article>,
  ) {}
}
```

And this is my test specs file

```
import { HttpModule, HttpService, INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { ArticleService } from './article.service';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';

describe('ArticleService', () => {
  let service: ArticleService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule, Model], // <- I set the model here
      providers: [ArticleService],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get<ArticleService>(ArticleService);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

So when I run **"npm test"** for testing, it returns the error

**ArticleService › should be defined**
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugin' of undefined**

I attach the error image for reference

[image]

Comment: Why is `model` in your `imports` array?

Comment: Really I was confuse about it, I think the test request that Model so I include it. I remove the model in the import array and now the test pass correctly!!